# $ (X,d)$ is a metric space and topology induced by a metric $\rho$ is topology induced by d then..

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

This question is number 3 of exercise 4.1 of Wayne patty's topology.

> Let $(X,d) $ be a compact metric space and let $\rho $ be any metric on $ X$ such that the topology induced by $\rho$ is topology induced by d. Prove that $(X, \rho)$ is bounded.

I have problem understanding what it means by  "topology induced by $\rho$ is the topology induced by d". $d$ will induce topology $d(x,y) = |x-y |$ and $\rho (x,y) = |x-y|$ and open sets can be given by $d(x,y)< \epsilon$ and $\rho (x,y) < \epsilon$ .I think it means that open sets  generated by them will be same.

Am I right?

In the case I am right I don't get any breakthrough on how it can be proved as using compactness ie open cover having finite subcover that $(X, \rho)$ is bounded?

Please help

Comment: this is very hard to understand. I don't want to edit the question as it uses a quote. Please double check whether the exercise is stated indeed as you quoted it.

Comment: @Syd It was correct except for a "the" which I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topology induced by a metric $\mu$ on $X$ is the topology whose base is the family

$$\{B_\mu(x,r):x\in X\text{ and }r>0\}$$

of open balls with respect to $\mu$. Metrics $d$ and $\rho$ on $X$ induce the same topology if the bases

$$\{B_d(x,r):x\in X\text{ and }r>0\}$$

and

$$\{B_\rho(x,r):x\in X\text{ and }r>0\}$$

generate the same topology, i.e., if the metric spaces $\langle X,d\rangle$ and $\langle X,\rho\rangle$ have the same open sets. Note, however, that in general this has nothing to do with $|x-y|$: there may well be no notion of subtraction of of absolute value in the space $X$.

HINT: Fix a point $p\in X$ and consider the family $$\mathscr{U}=\{B_\rho(p,n):n\in\Bbb Z^+\}\,.$$ Verify that $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$ and apply the compactness of $\langle X,d\rangle$.